# Как отобразить вложенность категорий joomla на странице материала?

Tags: php, joomla, cms, joomla3

Необходимо на странице материала компонента К2 отобразить вложенность категорий, т.н. навигационная цепочка, т.н. "хлебные крошки". Стандартный breadcumbs не подходит, так как все материалы привязываются к пункту меню и все URL's имеют вид www.site/article (без вложенностей), а в самом компоненте К2 материал может находится в cat/subcat1/subcat2/article.
Спасибо за помощь!